# Not able to use INTENT_VIEW in android pie it 's showing nothing

Tags: java, android, android-intent, actionview

I am making an application which uses intent to call all the application in the device with UPI. My code works fine before Android Pie but, in android pie it's showing nothing.

Here is my code:

```java
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(upi_link));
    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent,getString(R.string.payupitext));
    startActivityForResult(chooser, 1, null);
```

I want to know if there is any update in the which i have to put,I have searched but found nothing.If anyone can help i would be extremely grateful.
Thanks

Comment: have you found a solution for this. It even works on android Q, but Pie for some reeason is brokem. It opens the PHOTOS app but a progress bar spins forever

Comment: Yes, I have found a code, that worked for me but again it is not working in latest MIUI version of MI phones

Comment: Can you provide this code that you found, please.